# LibreOffice takes 30 seconds to start. OO started almost immediately

Tags: libreoffice

Installed LibreOffice, no problems but when I click on LibreWriter it takes 30 seconds before it's ready to go. I played with Memory in Options, no improvement. I unchecked Java, no improvement.

Comment: Was that the first time you opened the application? Sometimes it is slow only during the first time, or immediately after some update.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the question ? You would like to understand why is it taking much longer ? Also please let us know how/where did you get it from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for two reasons:

1. It is a bug, and should be reported if it still occurs.
2. It is an issue with a much older version of LibreOffice, and the answers would be of little use to current users.

Answer (score 9):

### Only applicable to older versions (pre-6.x)

Try using the systray quickstarter. Openoffice most likely is, and that is why it starts immediately.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a known problem, at least on Arch Linux.

The problem is that LibreOffice tries to communicate with a WINS server (provided by Samba, I guess). If you do not have such server LibreOffice waits until the packets time out before continue loading.

Info taken from: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/22693

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run

```
libreoffice
```

and post back the output from this into your original question.

On my Toshiba U400 laptop (3Gb ram, 2Ghz CPU), that command completes in less than a second with no output to the terminal.  I have, like you, unticked "Java", but otherwise, it's pretty much a stock install from the [Libreoffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) outlined at [OMGUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/libreoffice-3-3-released/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with LibreOffcie and OpenOffice all the years ago and thought this was normal. However, since a few days the program start within 3 seconds now.

One of the recent Ubuntu upgrades fixed this.

I am using the stable distribution (12.04)